# Merge arraylist of maps in json, java

Tags: java, json, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I have 2 arraylists(of same size) in json as below:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> list1 = new Arraylist<HashMap<String, String>>();

List<HashMap<String, String>> list2 = new Arraylist<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

I want to merge the above lists into a single one.

For ex:

List1:

```
[{ " key1": "value1", " key2": "value2"}, 
{ " key11": "value11", " key22": "value22"}]
```

List2:

```
[{ " key3": "value3"},{" key33": "value33"}]
```

Expected output:

```
[{ " key1": "value1", " key2": "value2", " key3": "value3"}, 
{ " key11": "value11", " key22": "value22", " key3": "value3"}]
```

An early response will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is your original input? Are these the JSON values or the Java POJOs?

Comment: Original input are the lists that I want to merge and are json values

Comment: Then have a look [here](https://github.com/fge/json-patch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expected output probably be:

> [{ " key1": "value1", " key2": "value2", " key3": "value3"}, 
>   { " key11": "value11", " key22": "value22", " key33": "value33"}]

You didn't indicate whether two lists had same size or not. According to your example, I assumed the lists had same size. So the code could be like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
  list1.get(i).putAll(list2.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Superb!! Thanks a tonne. This is what i was looking for. I will edit the question to mention about the same size.

Answer (score 2):

If the two ArrayList have the same type (they seem to be arraylist of maps):

```
 list1.addAll(list2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. list1.addAll(list2) gives the following O/p:          [{{ " key1": "value1", " key2": "value2"},{ " key3": "value3"}}, 
{{ " key11": "value11", " key22": "value22"},{ " key3": "value3"}}]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** you can do like this

```
    for (HashMap<String, String> m : list2) {
        HashMap<String, String> t = list1.get(list2.indexOf(m));
        for(String key: t.keySet()){
            m.put(key, t.get(key));
        }
    }
```

Now Merged items are in list2.

Comment: Thanks for your response. list1.addAll(list2) doesnt give the expected O/p i.e. it gives: [{{ " key1": "value1", " key2": "value2"},{ " key3": "value3"}}, {{ " key11": "value11", " key22": "value22"},{ " key3": "value3"}}]

Comment: I have checked, the correct json is : `[{" key1":"value1"," key2":"value2"},{" key3":"value3"},{" key11":"value11"," key22":"value22"},{" key3":"value3"}]`

your json is invalid in 1st place `[{{ " key1": "value1", " key2": "value2"},{ " key3": "value3"}}, {{ " key11": "value11", " key22": "value22"},{ " key3": "value3"}}] ` how you have got this wrong one ?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. As you have noted, after doing list1.addAll(list2)... O/P is [{" key1":"value1"," key2":"value2"},{" key3":"value3"},{" key11":"value11"," key22":"value22"},{" key3":"value3"}]. However as stated in the question, the O/P I need is:   [{ " key1": "value1", " key2": "value2", " key3": "value3"}, 
{ " key11": "value11", " key22": "value22", " key3": "value3"}]

Comment: Ahh, I got it you want to merge objects rather lists. I guess there is no built in method for this you have to write it on your own.

Comment: See my Edit on answer i wrote code for you :) which generate json of yours `[{" key1":"value1"," key2":"value2"," key3":"value3"},{" key11":"value11"," key22":"value22"," key3":"value3"}]`

Answer (score 0):

You Just have to retrieve the Hashmap from the individual Lists and then merge them all together

for eg

```
HashMap m = new HashMap();
        m.put("key1", "val1");
        m.put("key2", "val2");

        HashMap m1 = new HashMap();
        m1.put("key3", "val3");
HashMap mergeMap = new HashMap();
        mergeMap.putAll(m);
        mergeMap.putAll(m1);

        System.out.println("Map:" + mergeMap);
```

Output

Map:{key3=val3, key2=val2, key1=val1}